# Prove that if $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers and $ xy+xz+yz = 1$ then $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} > 2$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that if $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers and $ xy+xz+yz = 1$ then  $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} > 2$$

I am having a hard time relating the square roots in the inequality to the given condition. I was thinking that maybe there is some substitution I could do, but I couldn't think of any.

Comment: At least to get rid of the radicals you could let $x=u^2,y=v^2,z=w^2,$

Comment: Then I get $u+v+w \geq 2$ and $u^2v^2+u^2w^2+v^2w^2 = 1$. Then what?

Comment: Ten bucks says this is a setup for AMGM.

Comment: I think that it is not $\ge 2$, but $>2$.

Comment: @ChadShin I think you are right I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Assume w.l.o.g. that $z \leq x,y$.

We have $(x+z)(y+z) =1+z^2$ and hence $\sqrt{(x+z)}+\sqrt{(y+z)} \geq 2(1+z^2)^{1/4}>2$.

Now it is sufficient to prove: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{z}/2 \geq \sqrt{x+z}$ and $\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}/2 \geq \sqrt{y+z}$.

It is sufficient to prove the first inequality which is equivalent to:
$ x+z/4+\sqrt{xz} \geq x+z$, or $\sqrt{x} \geq 3\sqrt{z}/4$ which is true.

Comment: A great solution. Just shows that it's necessary to break the symmetry once in a while. Do you have a lot of experience solving inequalities?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying the inequalities on this site, with limited success. In this case, I realized that $(1,1,0)$ is tight,  rather than $x=y=z$, which somehow helped because the A.M.-G.M. works best when the tight case has all variables equal.

Comment: Nice. +1. I gave another solution for the sake of alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution.

We show that
$$(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})^4 \ge 16(xy+yz+zx) \quad\forall x,y,z \ge 0$$
or 
$$(a+b+c)^4 \ge 16(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2) \quad\forall a,b,c \ge 0.$$
WLOG, assume that $a=\max(a,b,c)$, then we have $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 = a^2(b+c)^2 + bc(bc-2a^2) \le a^2(b+c)^2.$$
Thus it reduces to prove $$(a+b+c)^4 \ge 16 a^2(b+c)^2$$
or equivalently
$$(a+b+c)^2 \ge 4 a(b+c),$$
which is true because $$(a+b+c)^2 - 4 a(b+c) = (a-b-c)^2 \ge 0.$$
Equality occurs when $a=b$ and $c=0$ or when $a=c$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt (not a full solution). The best I was able to achieve is this inequality:

> $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}>\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=1.93185\dots$$

We will use the mean inequalities:

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}} \geq \frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}}$$

By squaring the first inequality and using $xy+xz+yz=1$ and $x,y,z>0$ we obtain:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 1$$

By adding $2=2(xy+xz+yz)$ we get:

$$x+y+z \geq \sqrt{3}$$

---

Additionally from the GM-HM inequality and using $xy+xz+yz=1$ we obtain:

$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq 3 xyz$$

$$xyz \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

I don't know how to use it here though.

---

Now let's denote:

$$a=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}$$

$$a^2=x+y+z+2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx}) \geq \sqrt{3}+2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx})$$

$$(a^2-\sqrt{3})^2  \geq 4 (1+2(z \sqrt{xy}+x \sqrt{yz}+y \sqrt{zx}))$$

Notice that:

$$z \sqrt{xy}+x \sqrt{yz}+y \sqrt{zx}=a \sqrt{xyz}$$

Then we obtain a polynomial inequality:

$$(a^2-\sqrt{3})^2  \geq 4 (1+2a \sqrt{xyz})$$

We need a lower bound for $xyz$, but the best I could come up with:

$$xyz>0$$

Using this trivial bound we obtain:

$$(a^2-\sqrt{3})^2  > 4$$

The positive solution is:

$$a>\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$$

---

I'll update if I manage to solve the original problem.

---

This may be useful (I got it by applying GM-HM inequality to three pairs of numbers):

$$\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx} \geq 2\frac{1+(x+y+z)xyz}{x+y+z-xyz}$$

And also by AM-GM for $\sqrt{xy},\sqrt{yz},\sqrt{zx}$ we have:

$$\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$